# PatsyError: Error evaluating factor:

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Estudiando el libro "Mastering Python for Data Science", intento construir un modelo de árbol de decisión de la siguiente manera.
Importo los datos y los deposito en un directorio nuevo que creado con este script.

```
"""Función que usa requests.py para imortar los datos de Internet. 
    Crea un directorio y deposita en el los datos descargados."""
import requests
CENSUS_DATASET = ("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",
                                 "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.names",
                                 "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test")
def download_data(path='data_1', urls=CENSUS_DATASET):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)    
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        name = os.path.basename(url)
        with open(os.path.join(path, name), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
download_data()
```

Nos posicionamos en el directorio creado e importamos los datos en un DataFrame. Renommbramos las columnas del DF

```
# Cambio de directorio 
os.chdir("G:\Py_machine_learning\data_1")
data = pd.read_csv('adult.data')
import pandas as pd
names = ['age','workclass','fnlwgt','education','education-num','marital-status',
                              'occupation','relationship','race','sex','capital-gain','capital-loss',
                              'hours-per-week','native-country','income']
data = pd.read_csv('adult.data', names = names)
```

A continuación intentamos crar el árbol de decisión.

```
data_test = data.copy(deep=True)
from patsy import dmatrices, dmatrix, demo_data
#data_test = pd.read_csv('adult_test.csv')
data_test = data_test.dropna(how='any')
formula = 'income ~ age + workclass + education + marital_status + occupation + race + sex + hours-per-week + native-country '
y_train,x_train = dmatrices(formula, data=data, return_type='dataframe')
y_test,x_test = dmatrices(formula, data=data_test, return_type='dataframe')
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Al ejecutarlo me devuelve el error

```
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'native' is not defined
    income ~ age + workclass + education + marital_status + occupation + race + sex + hours-per-week + native-country
```

¿Cual puede ser la causa, dado que no existe ninguna columna "native" en el DF?.
Agradeceré vuestra ayuda

Comment: ¿Será `native_country` en vez de `native-country`? (bueno, y lo mismo con `hours-per-week`)

Comment: Creo que no, porque antes de la importación he definido la lista "names" con las etiquetas que quiero para cada columna, que a su vez son iguales a las seleccionadas después para la "formula".

Comment: Ya, pero es que esos nombres de columna quizás no sean válidos para luego ser usados en una fórmula patsy, pues el guión puede tomarse por una resta. Prueba a darles otro nombre.

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en los guiónes incluidos en algunos de los nombres de las columnas, que eran tomados en la formula como restas. Los he sustituido por guiónes bajos y el problema se ha resuelto.